# Heredoc <<< or <<?

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-highlighting, heredoc

Well I am wondering what is the right way to do the Heredoc syntax?

In my code editor, which is 'e-text editor' doing `<<<` totally throws off the syntax highlighting.

[image]

and doing << instead doesn't.

[image]

code:

```
private function buildDB() {
        // build database
        $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testDB (
                title VARCHAR(150),
                bodytext TEXT,
                created VARCHAR(100);   
            )
                MYSQL_QUERY;

                return mysql_query($sql);
    }
```

Which is the right way? I am still very noobish so no idea.

or maybe I shouldn't rely on syntax highlighting eh?
:/

Comment: You can also **run** the code and see what happens ;-P

Comment: Not all editors support heredoc strings for their syntax highlighting.

Comment: ^ it does. I just had space before it. thank you ;)

Comment: take a look at the official php website -> http://br.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at example 2: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

It is `<<<`

You need to put the ending `MYSQL;` on the beginning of the line without any whitespace. That's why your editor won't highlight it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The closing of the HEREDOC string most be on a new line *without spaces before it*, so `MYSQL_QUERY;` must be at the start of the line, without whitespace before or after.